# Number of homomorphisms $\mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3\to\mathbb Z_9$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I had this wonderful idea: $f$ is homomorphism: $G\to H$, $|G| = |\ker f| \cdot |\operatorname{im} f|$, $\ker f$ - subgroup of $G$, and $\operatorname{im} f$ - subgroup of $H$, so their orders must be divisors of orders of their groups. So I looked for divisors of $3\cdot 3$ and $9$: $1$, $3$ and $9$. $9 = 1\cdot 9 = 3\cdot 3 = 9\cdot 1$, so there must be three homomorphisms, but apparently this isn't right answer. Is there a seed of truth in my idea, and which is the right way to solve this? Idea worked beatifully on $\mathbb Z_n\to \mathbb Z_m$.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two different homomorphisms $\mathbb Z_3\times\mathbb Z_3\to\mathbb Z_9$ which have kernels of equal size, for example $f$ defined by $(1,0)\mapsto 3$, $(0,1)\mapsto 0$ and $g$ defined by $(1,0)\mapsto 0$, $(0,1)\mapsto 3$ both have $|\ker f|=|\ker g|= 3$. So counting the number of possible kernel cardinalities is not enough to count all homomorphisms.

Since any homomorphism is defined by the images of a generating set, you need to figure out the possible images for $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ that define a homomorphism. Be aware that for example $(1,0)\mapsto 1$ can not give you a homomorphism, do you know why?

Any homomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb Z_3\times\mathbb Z_3\to\mathbb Z_9$ satisfies
$$
0 = \varphi(0,0) = \varphi\left(3\cdot(1,0)\right) = 3\cdot\varphi(1,0),
$$
where $3\cdot g$ is just a notation for $g+g+g$.

Now assume $\varphi(1,0)=1$ then this equation becomes $0=3$, which is wrong even in $\mathbb Z_9$. In general the order of $\varphi(g)$ has to be a divisor of the order of $g$.

Comment: >So counting the number of possible kernel cardinalities is not enough to count all homomorphisms.
But I can use it in other examples? If yes, in which? Where I have only one generator?

>Be aware that for example (1,0)↦1 can not give you a homomorphism, do you know why?
No, I really don't.

Comment: @DarkArchon I explained that in my edit.

Comment: @DarkArchon In $\mathbb Z_n$ you have only one subgroup of order $d$ for each divisor $d\mid n$, thus the cardinality of the kernel already tells you what the kernel is in that case.

Comment: Is this right only for $Zn$, or I can do it for $Sn$, for example?

Comment: I'm not even sure how you did it for $\mathbb Z_n$, but it certainly won't work for $S_n$ since you have different normal subgroups of equal order here in general. Stick to counting homomorphisms, there's really no relation to counting subgroups in general.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a different approach...

Hint: $(1,0)$ must be sent to $0$ or an element of order 3, and the same holds for $(0,1)$. What are the options?

Comment: As I understand - only 0 or 3, because 3 is the only element for which x*3 = 0 (mod 9).

Comment: So the only possible homomorphisms are: (1,0) ↦ 0 or 3, (0,1) ↦ 0 or 3 - 4 homomorphisms?

Comment: There are two elements of order 3 in ${\mathbb Z}_9$, 3 and 6.

Comment: So you have 3 x 3 = 9 possibilities. Now show they all can happen.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: $(a,b) = (a,0) + (0,b)$, and $(a,0) = (1,0)$ added to itself $a$ times. Similar for $(0,b)$. So you can figure out what $(a,b)$ gets mapped to. Show that this satisfies the definition of homomorphism for any of these possibilities.

Comment: I know the definition of homomorphism, but I really don't know how to apply it here, except for something like this: (a,b) gets mapped to ((0,3,6)a + (0,3,6)b). Homomorphism: (a,b) + (c,d) = (a+c, b+d) ↦ ((0,3,6)(a+c) + (0,3,6)(b+d))...

Comment: That's basically it. You just have to verify that (a + c, b + d) gets sent to the image of (a,b) plus the image of (c,d). Pretty straightforward.